# How do you clean up your GRUB 2 boot menu?

Tags: boot, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I to remove or hide old kernel versions, to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-to-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

When my computer initially boots up it lists about 8 different options. How can I clean this up to limit my selection to only one, the current installation?

At one time I was able to clean these up via Synaptic Package Manager but now when I type in the version number (ex. 2.6.35-25) for SPM to locate I can't find them to delete. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @Anwar It's definitely a dupe of that one, but the title makes it difficult for some users to find. I'm going to edit the other one to make it more search-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your Grub entries.

Open a terminal and type:

`sudo su`
`gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Find the lines that start with `menuentry 'Ubuntu ...`

Each of these lines is one entry of your Grub. To clean your Grub simple comment the lines corresponding to the entries you want to hide.

Comment them with the `#` character at the beggining of the line.

A commented entry will look like this:

> #menuentry 'Ubuntu, con Linux 3.2.0-25 ...

Save and reboot.